# Which Transformer for 220v to 24VAC for Heating Smart Thermostat

Tags: thermostat, heat

I have a 220V electric baseboard heating system which is controlled by a 24 VAC 2 wire thermostat (RH, W). There is a 220V to 24VAC relay in the circuit from the thermostat to the heating system.

I plan to replace the thermostat with a WiFi enabled smart thermostat so I can control it remotely. The Smart thermostat (Emerson Sensi) needs a C wire (return ?) so the thermostat can be powered.

My choices are 
1. Use an external 110V to 24VAC adapter from an outlet to power the thermostat (connect to C and R terminals on the thermostat)
2. Replace the existing relay with a transformer that has a common wire and pull a 3 wire thermostat cable through the floor & wall.

I plan to do option 1 now as it's zero risk in the middle of winter and follow up with Option 2 in the summer.
I'm not sure which transformer I need to get for the 3 wire (RH, W, C) application.
Any ideas ?

Also, the current thermostat has a backlight feature operated by a button to light up the dial - so, it is able to use the power from the RH wire to close the circuit. Can I simply jump the RH connector to the C connector in the thermostat ? I have a feeling this will cause a short.

Thanks, V

Comment: What's the contact rating on the existing relay? (Or how much power do your baseboards pull, for that matter?)

Comment: 25 Amps @ 240VAC.  18 Feet of baseboard length (6 + 8 + 4)

Comment: Would this work  ?  AUBE RC840T-240 ON/OFF SWITCHING ELECTRIC HEATING RELAY WITH BUILT-IN 24 V TRANSFORMER   . [link]http://www.smarthome.com/aube-rc840t-240-on-off-switching-electric-heating-relay-with-built-in-24-v-transformer.html?src=Froogle&gclid=CI2nn7vN1MoCFYEsHwodCRMCsg

Comment: You want a standalone relay @Vasuvius -- I'll link one in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

My plan worked perfectly and I called Emerson Sensi customer service to check that it will not cause any issues and the confirmed.
The 2 wires to the 24VAC relay that control the baseboard get connected to the Rh and W terminals on the thermostat.
I cut the jumper between Rh and Rc to ensure I wouldn't cause a short by adding another power source
I used an external 24VAC transformer, connected to Rc and C to provide power to the thermostat.
In essence this is not a parallel circuit situation, but 2 independent circuits. 
One circuit from the external transformer provides power to the thermostat. The other circuit controls heat activation.

Answer (score 1):

First off -- option 1 will be...awkward.  You are essentially connecting two transformers in not-quite-parallel here, and as a result, it may not work at all.  I would recommend against it -- simply replace the thermostat in the summertime.

As to a replacement transformer -- you can get a 240VAC to 24VAC control transformer as a [standard part](http://www.grainger.com/product/DAYTON-Control-Transformer-31EH75?functionCode=P2IDP2PCP) from an industrial or electrical supply house, as they are commonly used in industrial work.  You'll also need a [separate 24VAC relay with 25A contacts](http://www.grainger.com/product/DAYTON-IEC-Control-Relay-6EAY2?s_pp=false&picUrl=//static.grainger.com/rp/s/is/image/Grainger/6EAX9_AS01?$smthumb$); again, an industrial, electrical, or HVAC supply house will have this.